# Facebook Graph API 2.9 ChangeLog - 90-Day Deprecations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The 90-Day Deprecations in Graph API [Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_9) states that:

> The following fields are deprecated for edges and dialogs that allow attaching links to posts:
>
> - `picture`
> - `name`
> - `caption`
> - `thumbnail`
> - `description`
>
> The edges and dialogs for which these are deprecated include `POST /{user-id}/feed`, `/{page-id}/feed`, `/{event-id}/feed`, and `/{group-id}/feed` as well as the `share` and `feed` dialogs.

I am creating an app that uses Graph API v2.9 to fetch posts from a public page using app access token and includes these fields in the request e.g.

> GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{page-id}/posts?access_token={app-token}&limit=10&fields=created_time,message,caption,description,icon,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count),link,name,picture,status_type,type,updated_time,id

Does it imply that after 90 days of release of v2.9, graph API GET calls like these will also not return the values for these fields in the response?

Comment: No, as what you quoted already says, this is in regard to POST requests. It applies when you _make_ posts via the API, not when you just read them.

Comment: ok Thanks @CBroe